# .NET Region intersection with lines

Tags: .net, graphics, system.drawing

I'm trying to check if line1 intersect line2. Line1 and line2 are DrawingPath object. I sketch the problem into this code:

```
let path1 = Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
path1.AddLine(0.f, 0.f, 10.f,10.f)
let rg = Region(path1)
let path2 = Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
path2.AddLine(10.f, 0.f, 0.f, 10.f)
//Region contains only path1
rg.Intersect(path2)
let g = this.CreateGraphics()
if rg.IsEmpty(g) then
  printfn "NO INTERSECTION"
```

This code produce always "NO INTERSECTION" printing. Why lines not intersect
each other?

I need to check if line x intersect path y.

Comment: Regions were designed to encapsulate a group of pixels.  It must contain at least 1 x 1 pixel to not be empty.  The intersection of two lines is not big enough.  Two polygons, at least 1 pixel wide, would work.

Answer (score 0):

you're initializing rg with the region of `pt` not of `path1` like I think you intended to.

`pt` isn't in the sample code, I'm guessing it is a point somewhere higher in your test code.

change it to `let rg = Region(path1)` and I bet it'll work

Comment: Error. Rewriting this code to paste here i forgot to change that var. should be path1

Answer (score 0):

Another point worth making is that AddLine() creates a line in the GraphicsPath, but the line has no actual width (i.e. a Width of zero), hence why it does not intersect.

You need to call Widen() on each of the lines which gives them some actual width, so then they have a region that can intersect with each other.

I have a little example below that shows how you could approach this problem - it was written to use with LinqPad ...

```
void Main()
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    Graphics g = panel.CreateGraphics();
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

    GraphicsPath rect = new GraphicsPath();
    rect.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10));

    GraphicsPath li = new GraphicsPath();                   // Intersects with Rect
    li.AddLine(new Point(1, 1), new Point(20, 10));
    li.Widen(p);

    GraphicsPath lc = new GraphicsPath();                   // Contained in Rect
    lc.AddLine(new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 2));
    lc.Widen(p);

    GraphicsPath ln = new GraphicsPath();                   // Not contained or intersect
    ln.AddLine(new Point(20, 20), new Point(30, 20));
    ln.Widen(p);

    HitTest(rect, li, g);
    HitTest(rect, lc, g);
    HitTest(rect, ln, g);

    g.Dispose();
    panel.Dispose();    
}

private void HitTest(GraphicsPath a, GraphicsPath b, Graphics g)
{
    Region ar = new Region(a);
    Region br = new Region(b);

    Region cr1 = ar.Clone();
    Region cr2 = ar.Clone();

    cr1.Union(br);
    cr2.Intersect(br);

    if (cr2.IsEmpty(g))
        ("No Intersect, No Contain").Dump();

    else if (cr1.Equals(ar, g))
        ("Contain").Dump();

    else 
        ("Intersect").Dump();   
}
```